# Select list options gets hide in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html-select, dropdown

I have one question related to select list in Firefox.

If I have select list with long length option and it is pulled to right. Whenever the select list appears after user click, the text in the option gets hide.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachin214/k1e7gj4b/1/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="header-right-container" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #eee;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group pull-right" style="width:150px"> <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></span>
          <select class="form-control input-sm pull-left">
            <option value="1">option 1 This is option which will be hide</option>
            <option value="2">option 2</option>
            <option value="3">option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there is any way to pull options to the left side after user click.

This works fine in Chrome but not in Firefox.
Chrome View is as after user click on select list

[image: In chrome it looks like]

Firefox View hides text after user click.

[image: In firefox it looks like]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see the problem, sorry. In both Chrome and Firefox the select dropdown is wide enough. In Chrome it extends out of the window, while Firefox displays it more to the left so that it falls fully inside the window.

Comment: Wait, are you displaying this on a screen too narrow to show the full text of the option on one line?

Comment: Yes @MrLister, I want to show full text in one line. In Chrome the list is pull to the left side but in firefox the list is not pulled to left and the text hide.

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the problem in FF and Chrome?

Comment: Hi @MrLister I have added screenshots for FF and Chrome

Comment: Strange. On my machine, Firefox looks pretty much like your Chrome screenshot, with the dropped down list inside the window. This is FF 50 on a Windows 8.1; what system are you using?

Comment: FF - 47.0.2 on a Windows 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution for above problem, we can give direction to select list as right to left which will display list as well as option at right side.
To display option to left side give text-align to left. 
Note that the direction is apply only for mozilla firefox as it works fine in Chrome and IE.

jsfiddle link is,
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sachin214/3tzt5zb1/1/).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="header-right-container" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="background-color: #eee;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-group pull-right" style="width:150px">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></span>
          <select class="form-control input-sm pull-left">
            <option value="1">option 1 This is option which will be hide</option>
            <option value="2">option 2</option>
            <option value="3">option 3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>            
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
  .row {
    padding: 10px;
  }
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
  select{
    direction:rtl;
  }
  option{
    text-align: left;
  }
</style>
```

The select arrow can be changed by using css.